# MySQL calculate RAM B+Tree's footprint for a single table (comparison with python data-struct)

Tags: mysql, performance, b-tree, b-tree-index

I have the below data that I am caching in Python now:

```
id   timestamp   data-string
```

The data-string size is ~87 bytes. Storing this optimally in python (using dict and having the timestamp pre-pended to the data-str with delimiter), the RAM costing per entry comes to ~198 bytes. This is quite big for the size of the cache I need.

I would like to try out storing the same in MySQL table, to see if I can save on RAM space. While doing so, I store this as:

```
id   timestamp   data-string
4B      4B
<---- PK ---->
```

I understand that MySQL will load the index of the InnoDB table (that's what I have now) into RAM. Therefore, the id (unique), timestamp and a pointer to the data-string will reside on RAM.

How do I calculate the complete RAM usage (ie including the meta-data) for the B+Tree of MySQL only for this new table?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many variables, padding, etc, that it is impractical to estimate how much *disk* space an InnoDB BTree will consume.  The 2x you quote is pretty good.  The buffer_pool is a *cache* in RAM, so you can't say that the BTree will consume as much *RAM* space as disk did.  Caching is on 16KB blocks.

(@ec5 has good info on the *current* size, on *disk*, of the index(es).)